# Telerik RadDropDownTree Unchecking Value Not Removing Selected Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadDropDown tree, if I click three of the options and then submit the selected value of the dropdown contains the expected three values. If I then remove 2 of the values, I'd expect to see 1 value left in the drop down selected values. Instead there is 4, the original 3 plus the only one now left. For whatever reason it never seems to remove values unless I explicitly clear all the entries.

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="ddlAlertType" runat="server" DropDownSettings-AutoWidth="Enabled" DataFieldID="Column4" DataTextField="Column1" DataValueField="Column4"
                                CheckBoxes="TriState" CheckNodeOnClick="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="sm-form-control">
                            </telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args)
    {
        __doPostBack('ddlAlertType','');
    }
```

Comment: Which version are you using? The current version does not provide with OnClientSelectedIndexChanged client-side event. (https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/dropdowntree/client-side-programming/events/overview)